# "Invalid slice" when ploting using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, slice

Python 2.7.5 and OSX 10.8 here

I'm trying to plot some datas I get from a file.
I'm trying to code a function where the user is able to plot from the point he wants, and have come to this part of code :

```
firstPoint = raw_input("1st point to be displayed is n° : ")

tbdata3 = hdulist[3].data
print(hdulist[3].header['TTYPE24'])
print tbdata3.field('DDL_FT_OPL')
print(hdulist[3].header['TTYPE23'])
print tbdata3.field('DDL_SC_OPL')

dataFT=tbdata3.field('DDL_FT_OPL')
plt.subplot(211)
plot(dataFT[firstPoint:400,:])
dataSC=tbdata3.field('DDL_SC_OPL')
plt.subplot(212)
plot(dataSC[firstPoint:400,:])
show()
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/geoffroysarrazin/Desktop/stage_observatoire/testEkki.py", line 52, in essai
plot(dataFT[firstPoint:400,:])
IndexError: invalid slice
```

And it seems weird to me, cause I got this with

```
firstPoint=10
```

and just before, I had a constant value instead of this input from the user, which was equal to 200 (or whatever <400) and it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - you're not converting your input!

```
firstPoint = int(raw_input("1st point to be displayed is n° : "))
```

You can add some exception handling to re-prompt the user if he doesn't provide a number, if you so wish.

Comment: Yeah thank's, I forgot to cast -____-"
Sorry for that question I feel even dumber than before ahah

Comment: It happens...frustratingly often.  And, to be fair, `invalid slice` isn't a very useful error message.